# What are the possible points to be consider if i create Business Manager for My Facebook App

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have recently noticed that facebook returns different auth ids for same app on different platforms.

We have a website and integrated Facebook login and implemented login using user id returned by facebook api.

It was working like a charm, but now we have created android and ios app , when we have tried to login by facebook with same user login which has already logged in from web platform returns different user id.

So my question is that which steps need to be taken to allow facebook login through android and ios app for users who has aready made signup on our web platform and how to make mappings if we use **Business Manager**

Comment: By “same app” you mean an app that looks/does the same, but uses a _different_ app id, right? (Because only then should you get different app-scoped user ids.) // Whether you assign your apps to a business or not, does not make a difference for the end user regarding “how” they log in, everything stays the same. And you will still be getting different, app-scoped user ids. You just get access to an additional field that holds a unique identifier that is the same across those apps assigned to the same business, so that you can identify the accounts from each app as belonging to the same user.